# Dump/restore Postgres DB without extensions

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on a script that "deploys" a DB from one environment to another (read: dump on A, restore on B).

For this, I utilize the built-in pg_dump and pg_restore:

```
pg_dump -v --host="$PGHOST" --username="$PGUSER" \
    --format=c \
    --no-password \
    --no-privileges \
    --no-owner \
    mydb > mydb.pg_dump
```

```
pg_restore -v --host="$PGHOST" --username="$PGUSER" --dbname="$PGNAME" \
    --format=c \
    --single-transaction \
    --clean \
    --if-exists \
    --no-password \
    --no-privileges \
    --no-owner \
    mydb.pg_dump
```

Howerver, because the target dbs is managed by our DevOps team, the user I'm operating under doesn't have all privileges, which results in this error when restoring:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  must be owner of extension pg_stat_statements
Command was: DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS pg_stat_statements;
```

How can I disable dump/restore of extensions? All I want is that the schema and data is replaced on the target system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-e` option that allows you to select a pattern for all extensions to be dumped. If you want none dumped, use `pg_catalog.plpgsql`, because objects from the system schema will be excluded:

```bash
pg_dump -e pg_catalog.plpgsql [other options] mydb
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we're using pg10, so `-e` is not available :-(

Comment: v10 will go out of service in a year or so. A good opportunity to upgrade.

Comment: I will pass it along ;-)